# Need to Add Visual Studio 2015 Shared Project References to a Github Repository

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015, reference

Okay, so, really quick question that I hope I can provide enough detail to get an answer for.

Programs used: Visual Studio 2015, Github

The problem is occurring whenever the developer makes a change that includes  the references within Visual Studio and commits his changes to our Github. I am our tester and am told that the code is ready for testing, only to find that I cannot compile at times due to the Project References not being correct. We have discovered that this is because Github does not synch changes to the References that a Project has. The Reference that is giving us the most problems is an internal reference to another project within the solution, and appears in the "Shared Projects" section of the Reference Manager in VS2015. The developer is trying to soothe these issues as well, but our progress is being slowed significantly by this problem while he searches for an in-code solution.

Is there a way to force Github to add these Reference changes when making a commit? Due to the terminology used, I have not been able to find a solution to the problem anywhere, or at least one that I understood. I am not well versed in Visual Studio, so I am not sure if there is an option to change somewhere or another simple fix. If there is, please let me know.

I hope that I have provided adequate information without breaking my company's NDA. If you need further info to aid in this matter, I can ask the developer for further clarification, although it may take up to 24 hours for him to respond. Thank you in advance!

Comment: GitHub is just a website that hosts Git repositories. Your developer needs to make sure they fully commit any changes to their code. That's got very little do with GitHub.

Comment: Project references are stored on the .csproj project file, check it's being updated correctly and the rererence paths aren't absolute but relative.

Comment: Gusman, that sounds like the most likely issue. I've noticed that minor changes to classes that I make when writing tests cause updates to the.csproj file. I wonder if he is saying no to the prompts to save the .csproj file and that's propagating the issue. I'll chat with him and look into it. Thank you!